# How to insert a WordPress plugin code using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, lightbox

I have a gallery plugin that can be inserted into WordPress using the code `[LBS id=xx]`.

How can I use this code in a custom PHP page, I need to insert this code into, using PHP?

Comment: Related: *[Is there a way to parse shortcodes in PHP?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30403)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo do_shortcode( '[LBS id=xx]' );
```

Comment: But in which context does this code run? In a plugin? In a theme? In a template? What files need to be included (and other things) for this to work? What about load order of themes and plugins? What are the limitations of where it can run, if any? It definitely does not run from raw PHP code.